# Selenium python click icon next to a certain text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have the following structure, where I am trying to click the second trash icon which is a button next to Test1.

```
<tr class=“ng-scope”>
  <td class=“ng-scope”></td>
  <td class=“ng-scope”></td>
  <td class=“ng-scope”>
     <span class=“ng-binding”>Test0</span>
   </td>
  <td class=“ng-scope”>
     <button class=“bin btn-xs”>
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
     </button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class=“ng-scope”>
  <td class=“ng-scope”></td>
  <td class=“ng-scope”></td>
  <td class=“ng-scope”>
     <span class=“ng-binding”>Test1</span>
   </td>
  <td class=“ng-scope”>
     <button class=“bin btn-xs”>
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
     </button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Currently how I am implementing is by doing `find_element_by_xpath` where xpath is `//i@class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"` and do an index searching with the given results.
This however I find quit inefficient, especially the given results can be theoretically many and I have to loop through the result list.

I tried also the following lines:

```
 myxpath = "//*[contains(text(), 'Test1')]/following-sibling::tr/button[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash']" 
 driver.find_by_xpath(myxpath)
```

which does not work (because the trash icon is not actually the sibling of Test1.

How can I implement this in a better way (i.e. I want to use Test1 as anchor and click the trash button next to it and not next to Test0)?

Comment: Try once `//span[text() ='Test1']/following::button` and let me know...

Comment: @SaurabhGaur no it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the button in the row having the text:

```
//tr[.//text()='Test1']//button
```

To select the button in cell 4 in the row having the text in cell 3:

```
//tr[td[3]//text()='Test1']/td[4]//button
```

To select the cell having the text and then the button in the following cell:

```
//td[.//text()='Test1']/following-sibling::td[1]//button"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very clear whether you want the button or the icon...
here is for the i tag

try

```
//i[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' and ../../../td/span/text() = "Test1"]
```

ps note also that:

```
<span class="ng-binding">Test1</span>
```

and

```
<span class="ng-binding"> Test1 </span>
```

are different.

Comment: there is no space before & after the text, I update the description